# Why do I have those warnings on Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I am following a Xcode tutorial. My code is exactly the same as the example on a tutorial but this warnings shows up.
variable 'guess's never muted;consider changing to 'let'constant
variable 'correctGuess's never muted;consider changing to 'let'constant

### Result of call to '==' is unused

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var correct = arc4random_uniform(5)

@IBOutlet var message: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var guessField: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    print(correct)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func CheckButton(sender: UIButton) {

    var guess = guessField.text  variable 'guess's never muted;consider changing to 'let'constant
    var correctGuess = String(correct)  variable 'correctGuess's never muted;consider changing to 'let'constant 

    if guess == correctGuess{
        message.text == "Correct Answer"    Result of call to '==' is unused
        message.textColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    else {
        message.text = "Wrong Answer, try again"
        message.textColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what warnings? what code?

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are never changing the value of those variables, which means that implicitly you are treating them as constants. The warning is saying that you never *mutate* the value. Therefore, it's suggesting that instead of using *var* and creating variables, you should use *let* and create constants. Since you never change the value of those variables, you should use `let` since it's safer and uses less memory than a variable. In essence, you are treating your variables as constants by never changing them.